# Chrome Bug Select/Display

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

This only seems to happen on Chrome but basically if I have a hidden element with select box inside it and I have some javascript make it display when I mouseover the parent element. The problem is that the select box can no longer be selected.
I have created a demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qmnRL/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="widget-wrapper">
Test
<div class="widget">
    <select>
        <option>Test</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.widget-wrapper').mouseover(function(){
   $('.widget').show();
});
$('.widget-wrapper').mouseout(function(){
   $('.widget').hide();
});
```

**CSS**

```
.widget {
    display: none;
}

.widget.over {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: The problem is the dropdown is not display inline/bloc. You're may have to have to mimic the select with a div or something so you can style it.

Comment: Why not using a CSS-only solution? `.widget-wrapper .widget { display: none; } .widget-wrapper:hover .widget { display: block; }`

Comment: @nietonfir your answer is the best.

Comment: @DamianDennis Created a proper answer, your welcome! ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I can't reproduce it on Chrome/OSX (I can select a value from the field), but I believe the problem is that it's hiding again when you hover the select, as that triggers a mouseout on the parent. Try mouseenter/mouseleave instead:

```
$('.widget-wrapper').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.widget').show();
});
$('.widget-wrapper').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.widget').hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qmnRL/1/

---

Also, what @nietonfir mentioned in the comments above: this can be solved entirely with CSS.

Comment: your solution also works and was what I was asking for as this is part of an application that I am not sure if the css solution above will work for just yet.

Comment: You should also mention that `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` don't bubble up from their children like `mouseover()` and `mouseout()`, because that's why OP is seeing this behaviour. See http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest to use a CSS-only solution:

```
.widget-wrapper .widget {
    display: none;
}
.widget-wrapper:hover .widget {
    display: block;
}
```

[edit] And the issues you have with your jQuery solution are described in the [documention](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/):

> This event type can cause many headaches due to event bubbling. For
>   instance, when the mouse pointer moves over the Inner element in this
>   example, a mouseover event will be sent to that, then trickle up to
>   Outer. This can trigger our bound mouseover handler at inopportune
>   times. See the discussion for .mouseenter() for a useful alternative.

In a [nutshell](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/): Use `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()`(if you really need to).

Answer (score 0):

When you click the select lost the parent element the hover
and select goes in active mode

```
.widget select{
    display:none;
}
.widget:hover select,
.widget select:active{
    display:block;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nsuq3/)

Answer (score -3):

The problem is that, while you have your mouse over the options, you are no longer hovering over the element. The options menu is a completely separate thing from the document, and it is not processed in the same way. This means that by activating the options list, you are mousing out of the element, causing it to be hidden.

There's no real way around this, so I would suggest making a "click to show/hide" control instead of relying on mouseover. It'll be more friendly to touch screens that way too.

Comment: This is not true, OP just used the wrong event. See http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/.